# ASP.NET MVC Local Report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rdlc, report

I'm using asp.net mvc.

When I try to access my **.rdlc report** using virtual directory, the report is asking for credentials and it is not being shown.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, it seems very strange. Especially cause you're using a local report. Are those database credentials or file system credentials?

Comment: Thanks but I had found the actual reason.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601364/an-error-occurred-during-local-report-processing-the-definition-of-the-report

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to open the report using javascript's window.open(url) and I was not specifying the project name at the start of the url parameter due to which it was asking for folder credentials.

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stackoverflow! Please leave responses to other users' answers as comments on their posts instead of adding a separate answer yourself - much less confusion :)

Comment: True, but my second post was an answer not a comment.