# RDLC report getting error An error occurred during local report processing

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, rdlc

My report is working all the while, until it suddenly hitting this error "An error occurred during local report processing." . I am not able to locate the actual problem.

```
_reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParameter); //<--Hit error
```

I have try the solution on [An error occurred during local report processing..The definition of the report '' is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601364/an-error-occurred-during-local-report-processing-the-definition-of-the-report) , but it is still not working

Please advice .

Comment: You need to provide bigger code sample to be able to even start guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the most generic error you can find working with `rdlc`.

You have to catch the `Exception` and give a look at the various levels of `InnerException`; i.e.:

```
ex.Message
ex.InnerException.Message
ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message
```

Comment: This is really the only right answer in this context.  The initial debugging info is going to be way more diagnostically relevant across the broad range of possible errors than a single answer ever could be.  Note that if you don't have compiler errors on the RDLC, then it's probably self sufficient.  Look for potential problems at the interface between the code that is loading the report and the report itself... i.e. do you have the same exact names used on parameters/datasets that you're passing in as you have defined in the report.

Comment: A procedure that works for me when there is ambiguity is: select the formulae cells, delete them one at a time and test until you find which particular one causes the problem. Then focus on it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to allow null the parameter you have,

i think you are sending a nothing value on that parameter and your parameter is not design to accept null value, so error will occur.
if the problem still there, try to add screen shot